# Does the location of a solar or wind generator impact its power output?

Tags: astroneer

Does it matter where one places a solar panel or wind generator as far as energy generation is concerned?

Do solar panels work the same in canyons or craters which sometimes limits sunlight?  or even what about underground?

Does the placement of wind generators have any impact?  Will they work the exactly the same enclosed or underground as they do out in the open above ground?

[image: solar generators]

Does the game have any logic that governs the placement of wind or solar generators?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Before patch 1.0 the wind system was very basic as in there is one global number that defines the current wind and it just changed semi-randomly over time.

In patch 1.0 the mention "Wind Refactor - New wind system" and people started to notice some improvements. Still, the generators don't seem to go off when, for example, attaching them to a truck and driving at full speed.

As far as i experienced, solar panels do in fact take into account if sunlights hit them. I learned that the hard way when i landed in a crater of a planet, where sun maybe hit for 4 hours ever day. Every planet has a different number to determine how much power is generated (because the sun is either closer or farther away).